# include borders and state abbreviations when using the map function with the mapproj library

Tags: r, dictionary

I have created a map of the continental USA using the mapproj package in R.

I know it is possible to include state borders and abbreviations, but I can't find any information in the documentation that explains how.

My code looks as follows, and produces the first map below:

```
map(database= "usa", col="grey80", fill=TRUE)
points(DF$lat, DF$lon, pch=20, cex=2, col="springgreen4")
```

and my image is:

[image]

I have seen similar maps that have state and borders in them -- for example, here is what I would like to model my map on  (please ignore the colors):

[image]

Any help with respect to how to get these two elements included in my map would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

(PS:  I don't mean to sound greedy...but if any also happens to have any idea how I can remove the border around my map, that would be absolutely fantastic!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you state outlines in green with transparent grey overlay:

```
map(database= "state", col="green", fill=FALSE)
map(database= "usa", col="#AAAAAA22", fill=TRUE,lty=0,add=TRUE)
```

(Added an "alpha" value to the grey color to let the borders "show through".  ... see `?rgb` and `?col2rgb`.) This add labels but very messily and with extra regions:

```
map.text(database="state", add=TRUE) #  Not advised
```

I think some more work with the `state` dataset in the datasets package would be needed to map abbreviations to the state centers.

```
?state
```

This seemed effective although you might want to make the text a bit smaller with cex=0.6:

```
text(x=state.center$x, y=state.center$y, state.abb)  # better
```

[image]

With some further tweaking you can remove some of the boundary by overwriting with white:

```
map(database= "state", col="green", fill=FALSE)
map(database= "usa", col="#FFFFFF", fill=FALSE,add=TRUE, lwd=1.5)   # the overwrite of boundary
map(database= "usa", col="#AAAAAA22", fill=TRUE,lty=0,add=TRUE)   # note the transparency
text(x=state.center$x, y=state.center$y, state.abb, cex=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, this works (almost) perfectly!  I am shooting for the same color scheme as the 2nd plot:  not green borders around the states.  I've tried this:  
map(database= "state", col="#000000", fill=FALSE)  
map(database= "usa", col="grey80", fill=TRUE,lty=0,add=TRUE)` but I can't seem to match the colors.  Do you know why the usa map covers up the states borders in my situation?

Comment: Because I used a transparent color and you did not. The last two hex digits (of eight) on my fill color spec was 22, so it was rather transparent and allowed the green borders to show through. If you want grey borders just change "green" to "grey".

Comment: BondedDust, I am impressed with your skills...can't express my gratitude enough! Thank you for saving me countless hours and helping me to increase my ability with this package.